# Setting up Firefox profile for WebDriver in Python not to ask popups on download

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know there are a bunch of other questions on this topic, but I can't seem to figure out why I can't set up a custom profile in Firefox when using selenium in Python 2.7.9. 
Here's my code:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

content_type = requests.head('url').headers['content-type']
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/users/me/downloads")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",content_type)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", content_type)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)
```

When I run my code to perform an automatic download I still get a popup box. The files I'm trying to download are csv's but the content type I get from running the code above is `"text/plain"`. I've also tried `"text/csv"` and `"text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel"`. Nothing has worked. I'm running Firefox 39.0.

Comment: All looks all good here. Can you set a breakpoint in test code, then open `about:config` in the WebDriver Firefox instance and verify the settings are there?